# POST HTTP 409 Conflict

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

When I submitting the form, I got this error message

> POST HTTP... 409 Conflict.

This happens when I created a `handleChange` function for every `onChange` event.

```
const handleChange = (evt) => {
    const { name, value } = evt.target;
    setPostData({ ...postData, [name]: value });
  };

const handleSubmit = async (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log(postData);
    dispatch(createPost(postData));
  };

<TextField
    variant="outlined"
    id="fullname"
    name="fullname"
    type="text"
    label="Full name"
    value={postData.fullname}
    onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: replace `setPostData` with this `setPostData(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));` and check

Comment: It's working now sir @NishargShah! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `setPostData` function with

```
setPostData(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
```

The problem in your old code is you are not getting the latest updated value but in my solution, it will always give you the updated and latest value

Comment: Noted, Thank you so much!